# How to increase ping time/network connection latency on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ping, gaming

I need to permanently increase network latency in approximately 100ms, without losing packets.

Reason: On a certain server and internet game my ping is too much lower than the other people playing it. I have 15ms, when average is 150ms which gives me cheater-like advantages.

So also out of curiosity I'm looking for ways to increase my ping while keeping connection stable. What are my options if any?

I thought about VPN services, but it seems like a bad option since games use UDP?

Is there any router/software that would assist me on this?

I'm on windows.

Comment: debatable if you get an advantage or disadvantage. for example in the 2D game soldat you need to have a high ping to have an advantage. most player activate a p2p client for that.

Comment: I see. Well, the game in question is an FPS called Red Orchestra. You don't get any advantage by being laggy. It's just unfair the way it is now, because the server is a few meters away from home (New York), and the people in my team are in South America, while the opponents are in Europe, so I get advantages over everybody. I won't be able to join the tournaments if I don't find a way to increase my ping.

Comment: Seed torrents? Set a connection/speed limit and seed linux distros. When torrenting - or even downloading - my ping goes all over the place.

Comment: That would make things unstable, as I'd probably lose lots of packets.

Comment: I don't know how to overcome your issue but i just wanted to chip in and say it's pretty stupid if you can't get into a tournament for having too good a connection.

Comment: You can use a ssh tunnel to some VPS that you own, but I'm not sure the game allows proxy, etc. Maybe using a linux box but again, too much effort. QoS and traffic shaping comes to mind. Check this http://superuser.com/a/129387/235569

Comment: I know Fiddler2 can add artificial latency, but that's only for HTTP connections. Theoretically, something similar is possible for arbitrary IP connections.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to cause artificial network packet loss or latency?](http://serverfault.com/q/130170/174582), [Preventing artificial latency or “Lag Hacking” in multiplayer games](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/31303/24507)

Comment: Related: [How do I simulate a low bandwidth, high latency environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/130354/1030702)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deliberately introduce a delay for incoming UDP packets](http://superuser.com/questions/173751/how-to-deliberately-introduce-a-delay-for-incoming-udp-packets), http://superuser.com/questions/147156/simulating-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-network-connection-on-linux

Comment: @techie007 While not explicitly specified, I think it's a reasonable assumption that the OS is (or at least could include) Windows if the purpose is gaming. Those questions/answers are either Linux or HTTP focused.

Comment: @Bob It's been explicity specified. See last sentence: "I'm on windows." =P

Comment: @RZB Ah, sorry, I didn't notice. Consider adding it to the tags?

Comment: @Bob Sure. There.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/). It's a breeze to use and works pretty good. Pings is stable, no packet loss. The only future problem is the 100mb of traffic limit. I'm not sure how fast I'll get to that just by playing games.

Comment: I would recommend trying to insert artificial delays locally, if possible - VPNs do put you at the mercy of an external provider/network, so their performance can vary, especially for gaming. That said, if you happen to own a server somewhere (even a cheap VPS), you can set up your own VPN endpoint with a little more control. Another potential disadvantage of VPNs is they typically retransmit in case of packet loss, while most FPS games use UDP and simply accept the loss, catching up with future packets. Retransmitting can incur significant delays (usually seen as latency spikes).

Comment: Good info. Do you know how I could insert artificial delays locally? It seems like a very doable thing for a router, but so unusual that it's been hard to find.

Comment: That's exactly what my answer attempts to address, though it's untested on Windows, and it's just a guess. You could try anyway, if you want.

Comment: From what I understand of your suggestion, it'd would still be an external VPN, the only difference is that I'd have control over it because I'd own the server. By locally I thought you meant to insert delays on my LAN router, before sending data anywhere.

Comment: The one I suggested in my answer (dummynet) has nothing to do with VPNs. It's effectively a network filter that, in this configuration, can hold requests for a specified amount of time based on a condition. It is *entirely* local, and runs on your machine. It can also run on some routers, but that's certainly not necessary. The example adds a 100ms delay to any requests from your machine to xkcd. You could do likewise for requests from your machine to your game server, and then from the game server to your machine.

Comment: In my first comment on your own answer, I suggested a VPN endpoint that you own as being (marginally) better than some other VPN service. But my primary suggestion remains - [use a local tool rather than routing through an external network](http://superuser.com/a/688674/117590).

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't notice you were the same person. Since I've already played a few matches and everything was ok, for now I'll stick to the easiest solution (openvpn), but I'll definitely try dummynet whenever I perceive instability and change accepted answer then. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You could give [dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) a shot:

> #### Adding Latency
>
> We can con­trol traf­fic by adding rules that match spe­cific packet data, and then send the pack­ets through a Dum­mynet pipe with added delay or packet loss. For exam­ple, we could add a 100 ms delay to all traf­fic head­ing to xkcd.com like so:
>
> ```
> $ sudo ipfw pipe 1 config delay 100ms
> $ sudo ipfw add 100 pipe 1 ip from any to xkcd.com
> 00100 pipe 1 ip from any to any dst-ip 107.6.106.82
> ```
>
> The first com­mand here con­fig­ures a Dum­mynet pipe with id 1, cre­at­ing the pipe if it did not already exist. The sec­ond com­mand cre­ates a rule num­bered 100, which matches pack­ets with the desired des­ti­na­tion address and routes them through the pipe. Note that any rule that attempts to pass pack­ets through a non-existant pipe will block traf­fic and throw an error, so do not for­get to con­fig­ure pipes before using them. Using list again allows us to view the updated ruleset.
>
> ```
> $ sudo ipfw list
> 00100 pipe 1 ip from any to 107.6.106.82
> 65535 allow ip from any to any
> ```
>
> Ping­ing xkcd.com should show a round-trip time of 100 ms plus what­ever the actual cur­rent latency is across the connection.
>
> ```
> $ ping xkcd.com
> PING xkcd.com (107.6.106.82): 56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from 107.6.106.82: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=117.092 ms
> 64 bytes from 107.6.106.82: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=124.583 ms
> 64 bytes from 107.6.106.82: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=117.916 ms
> 64 bytes from 107.6.106.82: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=121.067 ms
> ```
>
> In most cases, we would want to sim­u­late a full duplex con­nec­tion by adding a cor­re­spond­ing rule for pack­ets com­ing from the remote host, so that the delay is applied in both direc­tions. When we are done play­ing with our new rule, we can delete it and the pipe as follows.
>
> ```
> $ sudo ipfw delete 100
> $ sudo ipfw pipe 1 delete
> ```

[source](http://blog.gradientstudios.com/2012/08/13/simulating-network-lag-for-testing-games/)

---

It looks like the dummynet project includes binaries for Windows. To adapt the commands, it should be enough to simply run the `ipfw` commands from an elevated command prompt. For example:

```
ipfw pipe 1 config delay 100ms
ipfw add 100 pipe 1 ip from any to server-ip
ipfw add 101 pipe 1 ip from server-ip to any
```